# iOS named pipes, works in ObjC, does not work in Swift, same code

Tags: ios, swift, system, named-pipes, darwin

I've been trying to use named pipes in iOS but it seems basically the same code in Swift fails while in ObjectiveC it works.

In Swift, the FileHandle for writing comes back nil, or if I use the FileHandle(forWritingAt: URL) API, it throws a Permission Denied. In Objective C the data is successfully sent through the pipe and logged.

The path in both of these is the exact same. The data in the Objective C example is also "hello".data(using: .utf8), though passed into the function.

Swift

```
  do {
    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: url)
  } catch let error {
    print("error deleting", error)
  }

  mkfifo(url.path, 0777)
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: url.path)
    fileHandle?.write("hello".data(using: .utf8)!)
  }

  let fileHandle = FileHandle(forReadingAtPath: url.path)
  if let data = fileHandle?.availableData {
    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))
  }
```

Objective C

```
  remove(path.UTF8String);
  mkfifo(path.UTF8String, 0777);
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSFileHandle *fileHandle=[NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath: path];
    [fileHandle writeData:data];
  });

  NSFileHandle *fileHandle=[NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath: path];
  NSData* read = fileHandle.availableData;
  NSLog([[NSString alloc] initWithData: read encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

These should just be calling the Objective C functions right? Why would they behave differently?
XCode 11.3, iOS 13

Comment: Why are you writing to the handle asynchronously, but reading synchronously? Both your ObjC and Swift examples are broken, because if the write isn't near-instant, the access ti `availableData` will happen before the write.

Comment: Does Swift have octal numbers? I dont think so. 0777 isnt what you think it is.

Comment: @gnasher729 you're right - ended up using 0x1FF and it works. Want to post as an answer and I can give you credit?

Comment: @ryangordon, even after changing the literal to 0x1FF, I still could not get your minimal example working. For some reason, the fileHandle hangs on the write.

Comment: ^ edit: found the issue. I had assumed your code block ran on the main thread, which it probably doesn't. This is because a write-only open will block until another process has the FIFO open for reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does Swift have octal numbers? I dont think so.
>   Swift does not have octal

I'm afraid Swift **does** have octal numbers, see [Integer Literals](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/LexicalStructure.html#ID414)

```
mkfifo(url.path, 0o777)
```

Answer (score 0):

I passed from here and I was looking for a complete solution for named pipes communication in swift.
and here is what I could do at the end.

```
private let path = "/tmp/myfifo"
func listen() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: self?.path ?? "")
            do {
              try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: url)
            } catch let error {
              print("error deleting", error)
            }

            mkfifo(url.path, 0o777)
            let fileHandle = FileHandle(forReadingAtPath: url.path)
            while true {
                if let data = fileHandle?.availableData {
                    if let readedData = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8), readedData != "" {
                        print(readedData)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

To Send(Write on the file handler)

```
   func sendToDeamon(content: String) {
        let handler = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: "/tmp/myfifo")
        let secData = content.data(using: .utf8)
        if let secData = secData {
            handler?.write(secData)
        }
        handler?.closeFile()
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

@gnasher729 was correct - Swift does not have octal so 0777 was wrong. I converted to octal to hex and replaced the literal with 0x1FF

Comment: I tried running the code you posted, but for some reason my iOS app hangs whenever it tries to write to the namedPipe. Could you post working code?

Comment: Swift _does_ support octal literals: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61019316/195661